# Testing server deployed on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, http, testing, post

I want to test a server I have deployed on GAE to see if a connection can be made via a HTTP POST request. The end client will run on Android but for now I would like to run a simple test on my laptop.

I send different "action" params as part of the request to the server and based on the action it will look for and handle other params to complete the request. Below is an example of how a command is handled. One param is the action and the other a username. It will in the end return a JSON object with the groups this user is a member of but for now I want to just get the test string "Just a test" back to see everything is working.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
.
.
.
.
        /* 
         * GET GROUPS
         * 
         * @param action == getGroups
         * @param user == the username of the user making the request
         */
        else if(request.getParameter("action").equals("getGroups")) {   
            /* Query for the User by username */
            User user = queryUser(request.getParameter("user"), pm);

            /* Generate the list of groups this user belongs to */
            ArrayList<Group> groups = null;
            if(user != null) {
                groups = new ArrayList<Group>(user.groups().size());
                for(Group group : user.groups()) 
                    groups.add(group);              
            }

        /* Send response back to the client */
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().write("Just a test");
        }
```

A side question, do I send HTTP POST requests to http://myapp.appspot.com/myapplink
or just to http://myapp.appspot.com/?

I have low experience writing client-server code so I was looking for help and examples of a simple POST request using supplied params and then reading the response back (with in my example the test string) and display it to the terminal.

Here is a sample of a test I was running:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String urlParameters = "action=getGroups&username=homer.simpson";
        String request = "http://myapp.appspot.com/myapplink";

        URL url = new URL(request); 
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setUseCaches (false);

        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        if ( connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ){
            System.out.println("Posted ok!");

            System.out.println("Res" + connection.getResponseMessage()); //OK read
            System.out.println("Size: "+connection.getContentLength()); // is 0
                System.out.println("RespCode: "+connection.getResponseCode()); // is 200
                System.out.println("RespMsg: "+connection.getResponseMessage()); // is 'OK'
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Bad post...");          
        } 
    }
```

When executing however, I get that it's a "bad post"

Comment: Check the answer below. But as a sidenote, I strongly recommend you to learn it using your own computer (localhost) as the server. You will be able to modify your code much faster than deploying it every time

Comment: here a list of tools to debug your http request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087185/http-testing-tool-easily-send-post-get-put

Comment: Have you tried submitting to the app using a standard HTML form? This will make it easier to determine where the error lies. Also, "I get that it's a 'bad post'" is not a stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you will want to send it to a particular link, so you have a way of separating the different servlet classes. Assuming that the `doPost()` method is inside `MyAppLinkServlet` class in the package `myapp`, you will need a `web.xml` file like the one below to describe how you will respond to the link. BTW, the code is only slightly modified from the GAE/J example at http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myapplink</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>myapp.MyAppLinkServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myapplink</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myapplink</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

On the server, try adding the line

```
response.setStatus(200);
```

(which effectively sets the status as "OK").

On the client side, try something simple to start, such as:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class TestRequest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String urlParameters = "action=getGroups&username=homer.simpson";
        String request = "http://myapp.appspot.com/myapplink";

        URL postUrl = new URL (request+"?"+urlParameters);
        System.out.println(readFromUrl(postUrl));
    }
    private static String readFromUrl (URL url) throws IOException {
        FetchOptions opt = FetchOptions.Builder.doNotValidateCertificate(); //depending on how did you install GAE, you might not need this anymore
        HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest (url, HTTPMethod.POST, opt);
        URLFetchService service = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService();
        HTTPResponse response = service.fetch(request);
        if (response.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        byte[] content = response.getContent();
            return new String(content);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I made sure everything was cool with the web.xml file and read into what it does more thoroughly. Your comment was also insightful as to how the server responds. I have edited my original post to include a test program I was running that fails when contacting the server at the link. Anything look wrong with my test approach code or is it something server side not being taken care of?

Comment: @mcorley I expanded the example a little bit, using the GAE API. The only other thing I can suggest you is to remove all the non-related code (such as the User and Groups part) until you know you have a good working response. Any error in that code will end up as a "Bad post..." log. You can add that back later.